# Cronjob issue (on SSL)

Tags: curl, cron

I'm tring to get curl cronjobs works on a joomla site.

> /usr/bin/curl -k --silent https://sito.com/en/?option=com_invitex&tmpl=component&task=mailto&pkey=welovemoda >/dev/null

I added the -k param because googling I see few users found problems with curl command and SSL.
But it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem you are facing is that you lack the use of quotes, so :

```
curl -k --silent 'https://sito.com/en/?option=com_invitex&tmpl=component&task=mailto&pkey=welovemoda'
```

If you don't do this, the shell take each `&` as a background job =)

Comment: I dunno what are you talking about. Mails ? oO